# How to add text before of an element's original text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some text **before** of the **original text** of an element.
Now, I know to insert text after the original content, I can do it using `createTextNode` like the example below:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
    $( ".text" ).append( document.createTextNode( " Hello" ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">Button</button>
<div class="text"> Some random text</text>
```

But how can I add it before?

Comment: did you tried jQuery.prepend()?

Comment: Thanks @whitelettersinblankpapers that worked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use prepend function. Also , no need of createTextNode.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $( ".text" ).prepend(" Hello");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8yukxftb/

Answer (score 1):

`.prepend` is the function you want.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
    $( ".text" ).prepend( document.createTextNode( " Hello" ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">Button</button>
<div class="text"> Some random text</text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you also just alter the text there? It doesn't seem from your example that there is anything wrong with

```
$( ".text" ).text(function(i,txt){ return "Hello " + txt });
```

Comment: No @TravisJ , that's why I'm trying to implement this hack with javascript

Comment: @Chun - Perhaps you should include in your example the scenario which leads to something like this not being an option. It is possible you are addressing the wrong aspect of the observed problem.

Comment: Sorry, I meant *no* to the "*Alter the text there*" part, the answer is good, +1! well [**this**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/206316/60217), is what I'm really trying to do, which is why I was trying to do this hack :\